# Codeigniter - database.php what is hostname for online server?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

i am uploading website on live server. In my database.php i set hostname as localhost but i give this error.

> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host
>   'webhost.daily.co.uk' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

thanks in advance

Comment: user name and password is wrong. Show code as well

Comment: They probably gave you the database information so you can set it up;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure like this

```
$db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost', // make sure hostname
        'username' => '', // username you created when created DB
        'password' => '', // password you created when created DB
        'database' => '', // DB name as well
```

[Codeigniter DB Settings](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html)